# ~/.my.cnf settings for a custom .mysql_history file

Tags: mysql, client

In my development environment I have a lot of databases, and I run the same query a lot of times. Long time ago I saw a post how to have a separated mysql_history per database. That allowed me to easily have in my history file only the queries that are relevant to that database.

My laptop died, and I haven't been able to find how to do that again.

I tried searching in the documentation, here, and in stackoverflow, but the only documentation I found was how to filter queries NOT to be stored in the history file, or how to disabled it completely.

I remember this setting was to be stored in the ~/.my.cnf file.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you.